# Extracting digits in the middle of a string using delimiters

Tags: java, string

```
String ccToken = "";
    String result = "ssl_transaction_type=CCGETTOKENssl_result=0ssl_token=4366738602809990ssl_card_number=41**********9990ssl_token_response=SUCCESS";
    String[] elavonResponse = result.split("=|ssl");
    for (String t : elavonResponse) {
          System.out.println(t);
    }
    ccToken = (elavonResponse[6]);
    System.out.println(ccToken);
```

I want to be able to grab a specific part of a string and store it in a variable. The way I'm currently doing it, is by splitting the string and then storing the value of the cell into my variable. Is there a way to specify that I want to store the digits after **"ssl_token="**?

I want my code to be able to obtain the value of **ssl_token** without having to worry about changes in the string that are not related to the token since I wont have control over the string. I have searched online but I can't find answers for my specific problem or I maybe using the wrong words for searching.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) with this regex [`.*ssl_token=(\\d+).*`](https://regex101.com/r/esTegi/1) :

```
String number = result.replaceAll(".*ssl_token=(\\d+).*", "$1");
```

Outputs

```
4366738602809990
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with regex.  It would probably be better to change the specifications of the input string so that each key/value pair is separated by an ampersand (&) so you could split it (similar to HTTP POST parameters).

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*ssl_token=([0-9]+).*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(result);

if(m.matches()) {
    long token = Long.parseLong(m.group(1));
    System.out.println(String.format("token: [%d]", token));
} else {
    System.out.println("token not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Search index of ssl_token. Create substring from that index. Convert substring to number. To number can extract number when it is at the beggining of the string.